# Campo de select preencher de acordo com código digitado em outro campo

Tags: php, mysql

Com base na imagem abaixo, gostaria que quando a pessoa passasse o cartão dela, fosse feito um select no mysql e onde está escrito a loja aparecesse a loja em que a pessoa é cadastrado.

Como poderia fazer processo ?

A dúvida maior é, como fazer o select usando o campo acima:(Operador)

Ou seja, seria um select dinâmico, que mudaria de acordo com o número do cartão do funcionário, e ainda mais, se não tivesse o cartão ele apareceria como por exemplo "Funcionário sem loja cadastrado."

[image]

Segue código atual:

```
<?php 
 include("conexao.php");

?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="pt-br" xml:lang="pt-br">
<head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/css/datatables.css">
  <script src="includes/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="includes/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="includes/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="includes/js/datatables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    // quando for alterado
    $("form").on("change", "#operador_logica", function() {
        $.ajax({url: "pega_loja.php?operador="+$("#operador_logica").val(), success: function(resultado) {
            // faz a lógica
            var json = $.parseJSON(resultado);
            $("#loja_logica").val(json.lojaNome);
        });
    }
}
</script>  
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12" style="text-align:center; margin: 0 auto;">
                <form class="form-horizontal" style="width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;" method="POST" action="imprimir.php">
                    <fieldset>
                         <legend>CONTROLE DE VASILHAMES</legend>
                         <div class="form-group">
                           <label for="operador" class="col-lg-2 control-label">OPERADOR(A):</label>
                           <div class="col-lg-10">
                             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="operador" name="operador" placeholder="PASSE SEU CARTÃO ...">
                           </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                           <label for="select" class="col-lg-2 control-label">LOJA:</label>
                           <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <?php
                             $operador = $_GET["operador"];
                              $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usu_cod = '".$operador."' LIMIT 1");
                              if(mysql_num_rows($q)) {
                                  $a = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
                                  $retorno["usu_num_loja"] = $a["usu_num_loja"];
                              } else {
                                  $retorno["usu_num_loja"] = false;
                              }

                              header("Content-Type: application/json");
                              echo json_encode($retorno);
                            ?>
                            Loja: <input type="text" name="loja" id="loja_logica" /><br />

                            </div>
                          </div>

                         <div class="form-group">
                           <label for="select" class="col-lg-2 control-label">VASILHAME:</label>
                           <div class="col-lg-10">
                           <select type="text" class="form-control" name="vasilhame" id="vasilhame">
                                <option selected value=''></option>
                                <?php  
                                $consulta_loja=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vasilhame ORDER BY vas_id ASC"); 
                                while ($dados = mysql_fetch_array($consulta_loja)) {
                                  echo("<option value='".$dados['vas_id']."'> ".$dados['vas_desc']."   </option>");}
                                   ?>
                              </select>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                           <label for="quantidade" class="col-lg-2 control-label">QUANTIDADE:</label>
                           <div class="col-lg-10">
                             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantidade" name="quantidade" placeholder="DIGITE A QUANTIDADE ...">
                           </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                           <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">GERAR CUPOM</button>
                           </div>
                         </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você usa Javascript? Pode fazer isso com AJAX. A biblioteca jQuery tem o método bem definido e fácil de usar.. Pode ter um arquivo PHP retornando um json e pegar ele com o AJAX.. Por ex, você tem este formulário:

```
<form>
Operador: <input type="text" name="operador" id="operador_logica" /><br />
Loja: <input type="text" name="loja" id="loja_logica" /><br />
<!-- continuação do código ... -->
</form>
```

E depois do jQuery instanciado no código, você faz mais ou menos assim:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    // quando for alterado
    $("form").on("change", "#operador_logica", function() {
        $.ajax({url: "pega_loja.php?operador="+$("#operador_logica").val(), success: function(resultado) {
            // faz a lógica
            var json = $.parseJSON(resultado);
            $("#loja_logica").val(json.lojaNome);
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

E o seu código PHP **pega_loja.php** fica assim:

```
<?php

// continuação do código de conexão ..

$operador = $_GET["operador"];
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tabela_lojas WHERE operador = '".$operador."' LIMIT 1");
if(mysql_num_rows($q)) {
    $a = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
    $retorno["lojaNome"] = $a["lojaNome"];
} else {
    $retorno["lojaNome"] = false;
}

header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($retorno);
```

Com a ideia da imagem que você passou, isso deve resolver.. Fiz aqui na unha, se tiver alguma dúvida, pergunta aí .. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Oi,desculpa a demora,eu tentei aqui e nao deu certo,possivelmente entendi errado,postei como ficou o código na pergunta.

Comment: Consegui acertar com sua dica,Obrigado.